# Arrow function and this inside a constructor function

Tags: javascript, constructor, this, arrow-functions

I have read this paragraph about the this keyword : https://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this

In this first case `this` refers to `global` objet, and it seems totally normal because when we have an arrow function, it automatically bind `this` with the one in the outer scope.

```js
var obj = {
      foo : () => console.log(this)
    }
console.log(obj);
obj.foo()
```

However, I'm not able to explain the following behavior :

```js
function bar(){
  this.foo = () => console.log(this)
} 

var obj = new bar()
console.log(obj);
obj.foo()
```

Now, `this` refers to `obj` instead of `global`. Why is that ? It seems to me that using the `new` keyword with the constructor function should return an object `obj` which is exactly identical as the one in the first example. And so the arrow function should have a `this` which refers to `global` and not to `obj`. Could you explain to me what's happening in the second case please ?

Comment: Whenever ES6+ confuses me, I look at a transpiled ES6->ES5 version of the code to understand it https://babeljs.io/repl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Functions `->` [No separate `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#No_separate_this)

> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) value (***a new object in the case of a constructor***, undefined in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) function calls, the base object if the function is called as an "object method", etc.). This proved to be less than ideal with an object-oriented style of programming

[Read more about the **`new`** keyword here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

> The constructor function ... is called with the specified arguments, and with `this` bound to the ***newly created object***.

*The bar() constructor defines `this` as itself.*

Comment: Thanks foor your answer. What I don't understand though, is that since foo is a function, what is inside is evaluated when the function is executed, isn't it ?

Comment: [Lexical Scoping](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/lexical-scoping-static-scoping) just means that it uses `this` from the code that contains the Arrow Function.  In your case, is using the context `this` of `function/constructor bar(){}`

Comment: Wow that's super intersting. Thanks a lot for these informations !

Answer (score 0):

Although I myself am far from good with objects (need to work on that), I think that when you do `const test = new Test()` you **initialize** a new object. That way, the scope(?) of `this` references only to the newly created object, thus why you do `this.foo` and later on you reference to that foo property by using `obj.foo`. On the other hand, when you just do `const obj = { .... }`, you don't actually initialize a new object, so the `this` goes straight to the global object - the window. So, `const test = new Test` creates a **new** object, while using only `const obj = {}` is **not** a new object and `this` by default goes to the window object.