# Issue with javascript call method

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, constructor, call

I want to access the details method of Vehicles from car constructor and want to print the name and type by calling without inheriting the Vehicles inside Car. Here's my code:

```
function Vehicles(name, type) {
  // console.log(name);
  this.name = name;
  this.type = type;
  this.getDetails = function() {
    console.log(this.name, this.type);
  }
}

function car(name, type) {
  this.NewVehicles = new Vehicles(name, type);
  // this.details = this.call(this.NewVehicles.getDetails);
  this.details = this.NewVehicles.call(this.getDetails);
}

const newCar = new car();
console.log(newCar.details("ss", "zxxzx"));
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
this.details = this.NewVehicles.call(this.getDetails);                             ^

TypeError: this.NewVehicles.call is not a function
    at new car (/temp/file.js:16:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/temp/file.js:19:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

Some miss-conceptions, some mistakes are there while calling newCar.details and the call method. Any help would be appreciated for resolving the issue.

Comment: Don't use arrow functions to create constructors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arrow function and this inside a constructor function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53146914/arrow-function-and-this-inside-a-constructor-function)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I updated the question. Getting different issue now.

Comment: You didn't update your question, you changed it to a totally different one.

Comment: @HereticMonkey After making the update as per your suggestion, getting this issue, that's why updated

Comment: You use the call method, but it is not correct. You have to call   this.details = this.NewVehicles.getDetails()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First parameter of call() should be "The value to use as this when calling func." See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

As for the inheritance :

```
function Vehicle(name, type) {
  this.name = name;
  this.type = type;
  this.getDetails = function() {
    console.log(this.name, this.type);
  }
}

function Car(name, type) {
    Vehicle.call(this, name, type);
}

const myCar = new Car("foo", "bar");

myCar.getDetails();
```

Should read : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance

Comment: No worries, you can also use class syntax : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes