# Can not use `this` in JSX at arrow functions of class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx

### Error Code

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.DemoRenderer = function () {
      return <div>DemoRenderer</div>;
    };
  }
  customerRender = () => {
     // I can use this here which is not the type of React.createElement
     console.log(this.DemoRenderer); // can console the function

    // However, there will be an error like the below. 
    // React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined
    return <this.DemoRenderer />;
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        hello
        {this.customerRender()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

When I rewrote the arrow function to the normal function, there was no error.

### Without Error code

```
  constructor(props) {
    // ...
    this.customerRender = this.customerRender.bind(this);
  }
  customerRender() {
    return <this.DemoRenderer />;
  };
```

package.json like the below.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "3.3.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

I also put the code to codesandbox, However, there was **no error** in the codesandbox about the **same code**. https://codesandbox.io/s/using-dot-notation-for-jsx-type-forked-ep2hhw?file=/src/index.js

Comment: I think you should not do `<this.DemoRenderer />`. Call the function instead. i.e. `this.renderSomething()`.

Comment: What is the goal here? It's relatively easy to write functions / methods where `this` points to something else, what are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1):

Probably a duplicate of [*Arrow function and this inside a constructor function*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53146914/arrow-function-and-this-inside-a-constructor-function). Arrow functions adopt the *this* of their enclosing execution context.

Class syntax in ECMAScript is just syntactic sugar. If you look at the classic way to define constructors and inherited methods what's happening makes more sense.

Arrow functions adopt the *this* of their enclosing execution context. I.e. it's lexically scoped (based on where the function appears in the code) whereas for function declarations and expressions, *this* is determined by how a function is called.

Consider the following:

```js
let globalObject = this;

function MyConstructor() {}

// arrowFn is global code, so its this is set to the global object
MyConstructor.prototype.arrowFn = obj => console.log(
  `arrow function\n` +
  `this === instance? ${this === obj}\n` +
  `this === globalObject? ${this == globalObject}`
);

// Function expressions and declarations get their this
// from how they're called
MyConstructor.prototype.fnExpr = function(obj){
  console.log(
    `function expression\n` +
    `this === instance? ${this === obj}\n` +
    `this === globalObject? ${this == globalObject}`
  );
};

function fnDeclaration(obj) {
  console.log(
    `function declaration\n` +
    `this === instance? ${this === obj}\n` +
    `this === globalObject? ${this == globalObject}`
  );
}

MyConstructor.prototype.fnDeclaration = fnDeclaration;

let myObj = new MyConstructor();

myObj.arrowFn(myObj);
myObj.fnExpr(myObj);
myObj.fnDeclaration(myObj);
```